# MinGW's gdb: Compiling linux code onto windows that uses OpenSSL causes seg fault

Tags: c, openssl, gdb, gtk, mingw

I've recently made an C application that encrypts files back and forth using OpenSSL AES functions, natively made on linux. The front end is uses GTK too. I've got it to build successfullyon windows, however when I start the encryption process I get a seg fault.

Normally I use gdb to find the issue. However the `backtrace` is not giving any line numbers that I can look into.

```
#0  0x6085da66 in strsep () from C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\msys-1.0.dll
#1  0x6082d5e7 in msys-1.0!calloc () from C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\msys-1.0.dll
#2  0x6088d381 in strftime () from C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\msys-1.0.dll
#3  0x6082d2e0 in msys-1.0!malloc () from C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\msys-1.0.dll
#4  0x62a02057 in msys-crypto-1.0.0!CRYPTO_malloc ()
   from C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\msys-crypto-1.0.0.dll
#5  0x00000064 in ?? ()
#6  0x62b0b380 in msys-crypto-1.0.0!RAND_version ()
   from C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\msys-crypto-1.0.0.dll
#7  0x77091ecd in ntdll!WinSqmSetIfMaxDWORD ()
   from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#8  0x632e7473 in ?? ()
#9  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

On linux -- which uses the exact same source and makefile -- does not crash and when I force a crash, gdb gives out line numbers that reference to the source code.

Why is gdb not reporting line numbers from my exe source code? If I could find that out I can ultimately discover the source of the seg fault.

Comment: I don't think there is any source code in `dll`s.

Comment: @Jezor It's not the dll's that I'm debuging, it's my exe file. I build it using `-O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0` so it should give line numbers when gdb detects a crash.

Comment: gdb is weird and needs extra pushing to load DWARF symbols stored in PE files (and to be fair this isn't the native way to store debugging info on Windows). Look for the `symbols-file` commands.

Comment: @andlabs This is unfortunate to hear. I may have to find a better way to cross platform build. I'm off to softwareengineering to seek a better way.